# Why Can't I Send email using JavaMail?

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, google-signin

Here's my code:

```
private void jb_emailActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("my_email@gmail.com","mypassword");
                }
                }
            );
        try{

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("my_email@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("my_recepient@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("hi this is me");
            message.setText("hi!");
            Transport.send(message);
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"message sent to your email");

        }catch(Exception e){
           System.out.append(e.getMessage());
        }


}
```

And whenever i click the button, it shows an error like this one:

534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 rs8sm2429742pbb.14 - gsmtp
534-5.7.14  Please log in via your web browser and
534-5.7.14 then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 dh1sm2432432pbd.49 - gsmtp

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: have you tried any of the options found on the support page?

Comment: it's good now. i just tried to use a different port. thanks though! :)